# How to Add UIImage to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to add my `UIImage` from web service to my NSMutableArray using this code:

```
for (int i=0; i<[totalRowCountString intValue]; i++)
{    
    NSString *criticsRatingString = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"movies.ratings.critics_rating"] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"criticsRatingString: %@", criticsRatingString);

    if ([criticsRatingString isEqualToString:@"Certified Fresh"])
    {
        self.ratingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rt_certified_fresh.png"];
    }
    else if ([criticsRatingString isEqualToString:@"Fresh"])
    {
        self.ratingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rt_fresh.png"];
    }
    else if ([criticsRatingString isEqualToString:@"Rotten"])
    {
        self.ratingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rt_rotten.png"];
    }
    else if ([criticsRatingString isEqualToString:@"Spilled"])
    {
        self.ratingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rt_spilled.png"];
    }
    else if ([criticsRatingString isEqualToString:@"Upright"])
    {
        self.ratingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rt_upright.png"];
    }

    [tomatorRatingImages addObject:self.ratingImage];
    NSLog(@"tomatoRatingImages: %@", tomatorRatingImages);
}
```

But my NSLog for tomatoRatingImages returns NULL. Any ideas why it returns NULL?

UPDATE: my NSMutableArray is already initialized in my viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize the array before adding objects to it.

```
NSMutableArray *tomatorRatingImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer. There was just a typo error somewhere in my viewWillAppear and I didn't initialized it properly. Thanks endy for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray * tomatorRatingImages =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[tomatorRatingImages  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rt_spilled.png"]];

[tomatorRatingImages  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rt_spilled1.png"]];

[tomatorRatingImages  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rt_spilled2.png"]];
```

you can enter multiple image in NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a property for the NSMutableArray instance, it's better to write getter to initialize it. It takes care of initializing the variable only ones also it gets loaded only when it's required.

```
   -(NSMutableArray *) tomatorRatingImages {
         if(_tomatorRatingImages == nil) {
               _tomatorRatingImages = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         }
         return _tomatorRatingImages;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize like this

```
NSMutableArray * tomatorRatingImages =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
```